# How to stop and start azure cloud service using windows azure management client

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to stop and start azure cloud service using windowsazure.management through code in my desktop application..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restarting Azure Worker role "WaWorkerHost.exe" manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809270/restarting-azure-worker-role-waworkerhost-exe-manually)

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this document: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-manage/?